# Is it possible to have multiple repeaters in a network with just 1 uniform SSID? Revision

Tags: wireless-access-point, tcpip, wireless-extender

In regards to [Is it possible to have multiple repeaters in a network with just 1 uniform SSID?](https://superuser.com/q/651554/364367), would you happen to have a diagram or possibly more information that has progressed or revolutionized this idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple repeaters with a uniform SSID (you may want to specify your needs better, typical "wifi repeaters" are horrible product which, to some degree, stuff the spectrum up for everyone.  On the other hand it is possible to build a large network with a single SSID and seamless roaming without the impact by being smart about how they are networked together (eg using 5.8 gig backbone and 2.4 gig for client access)